# Data.table: combine columns (individual function of aggregation)

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data similar to

`foo <- data.table(uid=c("a","b", "c"), var1=c(T, F, F), var2=c(F, T, F))`

and I want to melt `(var1, var2)` into `var3`, using a function that uses the following aggregation:

- `w IF var1 == T & var2 == T` (else:)
- `x IF var1 == T`
- `y IF var2 == T`
- `z IF var1 == F & var2 == F`

That is, given my `foo`, the expected result is

```
uid var3
  a    x
  b    y
  c    z
```

Moreover, any additional column that `foo` has besides `(var1, var2)` should be taken over into the new `data.table`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally dislike `ifelse`, and particularly nested `ifelse`s.. :). I think, in this case, we can do without it with something like this perhaps?

```
foo[, `:=`(var3 = factor(2*var1+var2, levels=3:0, labels=c("w","x","y","z")), 
           var2 = NULL, var1 = NULL)]
#    uid var3
# 1:   a    x
# 2:   b    y
# 3:   c    z
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way would be:

```
foo1 <- CJ(var1 = c(T,F), var2 = c(T,F))[, var3 := c('z', 'y', 'x', 'w')]
setkey(foo, var1, var2)

foo[foo1, var3 :=i.var3][order(uid)][, c(1L, 4L)]
#   uid var3
#1:   a    x
#2:   b    y
#3:   c    z
```

Comment: @eddi. thanks for the edit. I was trying the `CJ` method, but somehow, var3 column didn't get right.

Comment: The sorting of `CJ` and `expand.grid` is different - might be where you ran into issues.

Comment: First time I see an intermediate "value matrix" used in `r`, nice skill to acquire.

Comment: @DavidArenburg not really, but I do find the approach to be very interesting :) @shadow's solution is the one you should compare the `set` one with.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably also not optimized, but I find it easier to read than @David Arenburg's solution.

```
foo[, `:=` (var3 = ifelse(var1 & var2, "w", ifelse(var1, "x", ifelse(var2, "y", "z"))), 
            var1 = NULL, var2 = NULL)]
foo
#    uid var3
# 1:   a    x
# 2:   b    y
# 3:   c    z
```

Answer (score 1):

I did some benchmark tests and it seems that the @akrun's solution is the fastest one for larger datasets. Had to make a few changes (with comments in code for all changes), to make results comparable, but that shouldn't affect performance much.

```
# setup of data
require(data.table)
require(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
Nsims <- 1e4 # size of dataset
foo <- data.table(uid = 1:Nsims,
                  var1 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), Nsims, TRUE), 
                  var2 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), Nsims, TRUE))
# benchmarktest
microbenchmark(
{ #@shadow
  foo1 <- copy(foo)
  foo1[, `:=` (var3=ifelse(var1&var2, "w", ifelse(var1, "x", ifelse(var2, "y", "z"))), 
               var1=NULL, var2=NULL)]
}
, 
{ #@Arun
  foo2 <- copy(foo)
  foo2[, `:=`(var3 = as.character(factor(2*var1+var2, levels=3:0, labels=c("w","x","y","z"))), 
              # used as.character to give same result as other solutions
              var2 = NULL, var1 = NULL)]
},
{ #@akrun
  foo3 <- copy(foo)
  foo.index <- CJ(var1 = c(T,F), var2 = c(T,F))[, var3 := c('z', 'y', 'x', 'w')]
  setkey(foo3, var1, var2)
  foo3 <- foo3[foo.index, var3 := i.var3][, `:=` (var1=NULL, var2=NULL)][order(uid)]
  # assigned to foo3 to get same result as other solutions and used var1:=NULL, etc to achieve OP's
  # requirement "Moreover, any additional column that foo has besides (var1, var2) should be taken over into the new data.table"
}
)
#        min        lq   median        uq      max neval
#  19.635460 19.801922 19.93224 20.814533 22.57868   100
#  12.611448 12.762514 12.79219 12.864043 48.10415   100
#   4.691303  4.945683  4.98808  5.084922  7.21636   100
#
# making sure they give the same solutions
all.equal(foo1, foo2)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(foo1, foo3)
# [1] TRUE
```